# How get CefSharp referrer to work with pximg.net in LoadRequest?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

How does LoadUrl and LoadRequest really work together? I'm trying to load a Pixiv picture directly by using LoadRequest to be a ble to set the correct referrer information. But I seem to miss something since I can't even load a page without referrer needed with LoadRequest?

I have googled this now for a couple of hours and tried and retried several possible solutions without any luck.

Here is the code I'm down to at the moment:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings();
            settings.CachePath = "C:\\temp\\CEF";
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loadPixiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().MainFrame.LoadUrl("https://www.pixiv.net");
        }

        private void loadPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CefSharp.IRequest req = CefSharp.Request.Create();
            req.SetReferrer("https://www.pixiv.net/", CefSharp.ReferrerPolicy.OriginOnlyOnTransitionCrossOrigin);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Url = "https://i.pximg.net/img-original/img/2023/04/13/07/59/31/107128881_p0.jpg";
            chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().MainFrame.LoadRequest(req);
        }
    }
```

loadPixiv_Click is used to simply login to Pixiv and set up the cookies and such.

I have tried this but it did not work? Nothing loads.

```
        private void loadPixiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CefSharp.IRequest req = CefSharp.Request.Create();
            req.Url = "https://www.pixiv.net";
            chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().MainFrame.LoadRequest(req);
        }
```

Some hits when googling states that you need to do a LoadUrl before you can run a LoadRequest? But the problem is that for LoadUrl to work with the pic-url above I need to also set a referrer and the referrer is not part of the LoadUrl function, it is part of the LoadRequest function as a part of the request sent to the function?

If I do this is obviously loads but the is (I think) only due to the LoadUrl and has nothing to do with LoadRequest...

```
        private void loadPixiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().MainFrame.LoadUrl("https://www.pixiv.net");        
            CefSharp.IRequest req = CefSharp.Request.Create();
            req.Url = "https://www.pixiv.net";
            chromiumWebBrowser1.GetBrowser().MainFrame.LoadRequest(req);
        }
```

I feel that I'm missing something here? Anyone have any input to get me further down the road to understand this?

My main goal is to get loadPic_Click to actually show the pic in the browser window of the app.

I'm using CefSharp 115.3.110.

Comment: You need to have performed a successful navigation from a `Url` of the same origin before you can call `LoadRequest`. You don't need to call `LoadUrl` immediately before.  See https://cefsharp.github.io/api/113.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_LoadRequest.htm Your other option is to simply modify the existing request. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#load-url-with-postdata for a post data example, the basics are the same. Just modify the existing request.